# TP-Link Archer 4TE drivers - where to get them from?

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, wireless, 19.10

while waiting for a PC to arrive I started looking into driver issues (this is my first PC I'm going to use Ubuntu on, previously I only dealt with it on laptops) and couldn't find much info on the mentioned wireless adapter.

I found some conflicting information on the plug-and-play support and now I'm confused. Will it work out of the box on Ubuntu (18.04, 20.04 in a few months) or do I need to manually install drivers?

If I'm not mistaken it has Realtek RTL8812AE chipset on board and I were only able to find Windows drivers (official).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RTL8812AE wireless chipset is supported by Ubuntu kernel since the 4.4 version. No separate drivers are needed.

If you have any real problems with that chipset, you can ask specific questions.

Comment: My bad, couldn't find any information whether it's supported by the kernel. Is there an up-to-date list showing supported chipsets?

Comment: For instance: https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/RTL8821AE.html